# How to know if a .pdf is up to date with .tex?

Tags: compiling

How can I know whether some `filename.pdf` file corresponds with it associated `filename.tex` file or the latter has been modified since last time and it must be compiled again?

I have Miktex distribution and use `pdflatex` through `latexmk`, tough I can sacrifice `latexmk`.

Some use case would be avoiding unnecessary long compile times.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx. You could open the pdf file with a text editor and search for `/CreationDate` to see when it was compiled.

Comment: doesn't latexmk do that automatically? I'd always assumed it would it's a basic feature of `make` and similar systems.

Comment: > doesn't latexmk do that automatically?

Nope. I ran `latexmk` twice in a row and the second time it ran as the first, without any indication of the file being already compiled.
Maybe with some option, but couldn't find any of that on the `-help` documentation for `latexmk`.

Comment: > You could open the pdf file with a text editor and search for /CreationDate to see when it was compiled.

I was looking for some automated way.